# Postfix: Permission denied trying to pipe bounced emails to a php script

Tags: php, pipe, postfix-mta, email-bounces

I'm trying to call my php script when an email bounces in Postfix but when an email bounces I get

```
May 23 19:45:17 development postfix/pipe[5394]: 2064C22132B: to=<ian@rar.com>, relay=bouncer, delay=3778, delays=3778/0.03/0/0.03, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: pipe: fatal: pipe_command: execvp /web/mailer/scripts/bouncer.php: Permission denied )
```

In the master.cf file I've got

```
bouncer unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe    flags=F user=bouncer argv=/web/mailer/scripts/bouncer.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}
```

And in main.cf

```
default_privs = bouncer
```

As far as I can see this should work, as it's not a root user but has permissions to execute the script if I su bouncer and run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm starting to go a bit mad, thank you!

Comment: Do you have execute permission for the file /web/mailer/scripts/bouncer.php

Comment: What are the permissions on `/web/mailer/scripts/bouncer.php`?

Comment: Sorted it thanks, file had the right permissions for the user but wrong context for selinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out selinux was getting in the way, fixed by changing the context on the bouncer.php file, sanity restored!

```
chcon -t postfix_pipe_t bouncer.php
```